# Facebook audience integration, stuck at second step

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network

I have integrated FAN with success. I can show banners and interstitials in test and not test mode. So, I have sent impressions to facebook but my current state in the integration shows this:

[image]

Shouldn't it be at third step? More Oddly my placements show like this:

[image]

So, by the status message it seems it has received requests and this is the only requirement I have found for facebook to start placement review.

So, does anybody know if this is how it works? Shouldn't I be at step 3 (Placements review)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information, suddenly my ad placements have get back to Enabled for testing only :/. What the hell is doing Facebook?

Comment: I have exactly same problem as you - http://i.imgur.com/ZaPGUVt.png However, note, there's minor difference between u and me. For "Placements Review" step, although it was not highlighted to blue, the icon is changed to "tick" instead of "3"

Comment: More information http://i.imgur.com/vBQ2uCj.png

Comment: Initially, I only include `compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.0'`, and able to display ads successfully. After keep having the yellow indicator for banner status, I try to add additional `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'` and `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);` in `onCreate`. But, that doesn't help.

Comment: I had this added previously. Still waiting for the thing to be approved. This is disheartening

Comment: Here's the support I'm getting from facebook team - https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1074999809253052

Comment: You seem your placements where approved after reading that thread... aren't you?

Comment: at my side, it is still shown not approved yet.

Comment: again, I can't understand how a firm like facebook can do things this way. Doing worse is a bit difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

After uploading the app to live Google Play Store, and wait for a week, I finally get the above screen-shot, without doing anything.

That's means, once you see the ads at your side, the only thing you need to do is to upload the app to live Google Play Store. After that, the only thing you need to do is **wait**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I discovered why I could not advance in the review process. Today I got this message from facebook:

```
Thank you for writing into Audience Network. 
I’m happy to explain more about the updated review process for apps.

First, make sure your that the newest version of your app is live in the app store. 
Then, once your app has been downloaded by a user and an ad request is delivered, the app 
will be enqueued for review. Please note that the review process should still only take 1-2
business days and that this request must be from a user that is not registered 
as a developer of the app ID on Facebook.
```

So, it seems that you need to have your app live and be downloaded by a user that is not registered as developer. This seems not good for publishers because if you have an app that is providing good money you won't see a penny during the review period.

Hope this clarifies the process a bit more.

Comment: I have followed these steps, 1. Create ads placement. 2. Integrate to app and do live the app. Test ads are showing when app run on emulator. But when I download app from google play store, ads now showing. This is happening from last 2 weeks. what did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had **EXACTLY** the same problem and my game was live in Google Play with 100+ download.

More then 10 days have passed! But my panel still shows: "Enabled for testing and received ad request recently".

Then I contacted to Facebook and the reply is:

> Thank you for writing in. My name is Andrea and I would be happy to
>   help you! There is currently a maintenance issue going on, which
>   affected the display of the dashboard. The placement is not displaying
>   as “enabled” in green, even though your app is approved. However, this
>   should not affect the ad delivery. Please let me know if you have any
>   other questions. Have a great week!

Comment: How did you contact them ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

> Before releasing your app to the store, it’s highly important that you
>   test the integration is working properly. When you run your app on the
>   simulator, test ads will show by default and indicate a successful end
>   to end ad serving in your app. When testing on a device however, you
>   must enable test ads by copying the hashed device ID that is printed
>   to the console and set it in code via a dedicated function.

And, the most important thing is this:

> Until your app is reviewed and approved by Facebook, only the admins
>   and the developers of your app will be served with Facebook Ads.

To conclude,

**App needs to be live before anyone can see the adds except developers.**